# Rails: protect from extra fields in model (mass assignment)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, security

I have a model `Secret` with 3 fields: `f1`, `f2` and `f3`.
I have **a form** where user can input **only** `f1` and `f2`. **Not `f3`**.
What is the best way to pass values to new object?

If I will write `@secret = Secret.new(params[:secret])`, evil user may pass `f3` to my model, and it will be saved in model.

What is the best way to prevent users from passing extra values?

I read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment and there are 3 variants:
1) Blacklist (`attr_protected :f3`)
2) Whitelist (`attr_accessible :f1, :f2`)
3) Global whitelist (force `attr_accessible` by configuration line `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true`)

What method is the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most paranoid (and thus the best) setting would be `attr_accessible :f1, :f2` combined with `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true`.

If you add any new attributes later (by adding migrations), you will have to activly enable the new attributes for mass asignment. If you just blacklist the forbidden ones, you might forget to add new attributes to your blacklist. This will not happen, if you use a whitelist.